# "ERROR FirebaseError: The caller does not have permission"

Tags: typescript, angularfire

I made an angularfire web app. During some time it worked properly, but after it started to show a random (frequent) "ERROR FirebaseError: The caller does not have permission" when trying to write on the database. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Please, May I have your help?

- The firebase SDK I am using is 9.14.0
- The language is TypeScript (angularfire)
- The IDE is Visual Studio Code

My firestore rules are:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /entradas/{entrada} {
        allow read: if true;
        allow create: if request.auth != null;
        allow update: if request.auth != null;
        allow delete: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

These are my routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: DiaryComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'diario', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'acceso', component: AccessComponent },
  { path: 'administracion', component: AdminComponent,
     data: { requiresLogin: true }, canActivate: [ AccessGuard ] },
];
```

This is my login routine where the user is sent to the admin panel, and there he/she could fill a form to write on the database:

```
acceso() {
    let subscriber = this.firebase
      .logIn(this.formUsuario.value.user, this.formUsuario.value.password)
      .subscribe((usr) => {
        this.ngZone.run(() => { this.router.navigate(['/administracion']); });
      });
    try {
      setTimeout(() => {
         subscriber.unsubscribe();
         }, 600000);
    } catch(error) {
      console.log(error);
    };
};
```

Here is the service where it is the observable:

```
saveEntrada(ent: Partial<Entrada>): Observable<any> {
      return from(this.db.collection('entradas').doc(id).update(ent));
  }
```

And this is the piece of code which attempts to write on the database:

```
@Injectable()
export class AccessGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private router: Router) { };

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): any {
    let requiresLogin = route.data.requiresLogin || false;
    if (requiresLogin) {
      this.afAuth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        if(user) {
          console.log('Usuario actual: ', user.email);
          return true;
        } else {
          console.log('Credenciales no válidas.');
          this.router.navigate(['/acceso']);
          return false;
        };
      });
    };
  };
}
@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin',
  templateUrl: './admin.component.html'
})
export class AdminComponent implements OnInit {

  okPublishEntrada: boolean = false;

  formPublicarEntrada = new FormGroup({
    titulo: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    contenido: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    fecha: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
  });

  constructor(private firebase: FirebaseService,
     private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
     private storage: AngularFireStorage,
     private router: Router) { };

  ngOnInit() {
    this.okPublishEntrada = false;
  }

  publishEntrada() {
    let entrada = this.formPublicarEntrada.value;
    if((entrada.titulo != '') && (entrada.contenido != '')
     && (entrada.fecha != ''))){
      let subscriber = this.firebase.saveEntrada(entrada)
         .subscribe(() => {
           console.log('Entrada publicada o actualizada.');
           this.okPublishEntrada = true;
         });
      try {
        setTimeout(() => {
           subscriber.unsubscribe();
           this.okPublishEntrada = false;
        }, 6000);
      } catch(error) {
        console.log(error);
      };
    };
  };
}
```

### Edit:

If I change the firestore rules to:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /entradas/{entrada} {
        allow read: if true;
        allow create: if true;
        allow update: if true;
        allow delete: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Then it works without problems, but it is not he proper solution...

Comment: What is `this.db` of the `saveEntrada` method? Is it the pure firebase library or the `@angular/fire` library ? Also with the first rules you showed any connected user can modify anything on your database, this is ok if you trust all the users only.

Comment: In the service where the observable is placed, I wrote `import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';`and in the constructor `private db: AngularFirestore`. My app only has one user.

Comment: Try to use everywhere english language no matter what kind of project you work on so people can help you.